# [Groovy Beta 1] Having trouble installing console_bridge required by vision_opencv

Tags: ros, osx, groovy-beta, macos-mountain-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed groovy beta following these [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) on OSX and all of the core ROS stuff is working.

I am having a difficult time getting the higher level packages I need built (vision_opencv and navigation). I get stuck on console_bridge (https://github.com/ros/console_bridge) which is required for class_loader and pluginlib.

Console_bridge doesn't seem to be a package … not sure what to do with it. Should I try to make a homebrew formula for it and install it as a system dependency? If **yes**, then I will need to figure out how to write a cmake or package config file for it ... haven't done that before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50191/%5Bgroovy-beta-1%5D-having-trouble-installing-console_bridge-required-by-vision_opencv/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am actively working on the general source install instructions:

http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source/New

Currently they are targeted at Ubuntu and have some problems still, but the important thing is that this page tells you how you can use `wstool` to get all of the packages for a given variant (like desktop or desktop-full) and how you can use the latest `rosdep` to fetch all dependencies (even on OS X Homebrew). I'll summarize those here:

```
$ mkdir ~/groovy_catkin
$ cd ~/groovy_catkin
$ wstool init src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make install
```

That should have fetched, resolved, built, and installed all of the wet (catkin) packages that make up the desktop variant into the `~/groovy_catkin/install` folder.  You can then source the `setup.bash` in that folder to source your newly built groovy space.

I have built and installed the desktop variant on OS X using Homebrew last week.  But there potentially remain some snags which have been fixed but not released yet. I am currently working my way through the desktop-full variant fixing things as I go (on Ubuntu and OS X).

The thing still lacking from the instructions I linked is the part where you download and build/use the dry (rosbuild) parts of the variant. I hope to have that part soon (it is not hard, I just haven't finished testing the wet stuff yet).

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-11**:
Thanks William. Great to see progress here. I see that the rosinstall files you use reference tarballs for specific versions. How are updates then supposed to work? I guess `wstool update` wouldn't do the job.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-12-11**:
That is something we have not addressed yet, but we will have a "devel" version of that url which will checkout everything instead, which could be updated.  We didn't do that initially because it was much faster to fetch the tarballs.